# how to assign a URL to imageView in swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, alamofire

I have JSON response for image after a post request

```
"profile_picture": "uploads/profile_pictures/18/file.jpeg"
```

if I combine the base URL and "profile_picture" url I can have the image // browsing on the web page

```
http://ms.XXX.net/uploads/profile_pictures/18/file.jpeg
```

I want to store that image url to a UIImageView and show that image on ImageView.Please guide me how do I do that. Below is how im trying.

```
image = "http://ms.XXX.net/"+"\(LoginSingleton.shared.pathImage!)"
imageView.image = image as? UIImage
```

Comment: you need to download that image first ... then assign it to imageview

Comment: you can use third party libraries that comes with caching ... `kingfisher` and `SDWebImage`  are good

Answer (score -2):

It would be ideal to use third party frameworks like SDWebImage, Kingfisher etc. for better user experience. But you can do it without them by getting the data from url asynchronously and then set the image.

```
    guard let url = URL(string: "image-url") else { return }
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            // Set the image to your image view
        }
    }
```